# Youtube Iframe API - Object # has no method 'q' [www-widgetapi-vflvlw_TO.js:23]

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-api, requirejs

This is wrapped in an AMD module (RequireJS) - so to implement `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` I had to attach it directly to the window object: which works.

```
/* Apologies for using the window object directly.. but blame Google. */
window.isYTReady = false;
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function(){
    console.log("YouTube API is ready!");
    window.isYTReady = true;
}
```

Then there's a click handler on an image element which creates a `YT.Player` object - which is where the code fails.

```
        this.$el.click(function(){
            if(! window.isYTReady ){
                console.log("Youtube API failed to load.");
                return false;
            }

            console.log("YouTube API has loaded, now interacting with YouTube API");

            var docHeight   = $('window').height(),
                docWidth    = $('window').width();

            // Take Youtube ID from the 'data-video' attribute
            _self.player = YT.Player('vidPlayer', {
                height:     '400', //docHeight,
                width:      '400', // docWidth,
                videoId:    'eHooBjxmoXQ', // _self.youtube,
                events: {
                    'onReady':          _self.playerReady,
                    'onStateChange':    _self.playerStateChange
                }
            });
        });
```

Here are the other functions mentioned:

```
        this.playerReady        = function(e){
            console.log("Player is ready");
            _self.modal.fadeIn();
            e.target.playVideo();
        };

        this.playerStateChange  = function(e){
            console.log("State has changed");
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                setTimeout(_self.stopVideo, 6000);
                done = true;
            }
        }
```

Neither of which run.

Now I've adjusted all of the arguments and still had no luck. I've even tried attaching the `playerReady` function directly to the window object to see if there were any scope issues present: none!

I know the API has loaded correctly because I get this in the console:

> YouTube API is ready! [player.js:6]
>
> event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. [jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5]
>
> YouTube API has loaded, now interacting with YouTube API [player.js:55]
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'q' [www-widgetapi-vflvlw_TO.js:23]

Naturally, as it's failing on the script that Youtube injects - it's all minified and hard to debug precisely. However a little digging shows this as the line in queston:

```
function db(a,b){for(var c=document.createElement("iframe"),d=b.attributes,e=0,f=d.length;e<f;e++){var m=d[e].value;null!=m&&""!=m&&"null"!=m&&c.setAttribute(d[e].name,m)}c.setAttribute("frameBorder",0);c.setAttribute("allowfullscreen",1);c.setAttribute("title","YouTube "+S(a.b,"title"));(d=S(a.b,"width"))&&c.setAttribute("width",d);(d=S(a.b,"height"))&&c.setAttribute("height",d);var r=a.q();r.enablejsapi=window.postMessage?1:0;window.location.host&&(r.origin=window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host);
```

I may try and work out what `a` is supposed to contain - so I can troubleshoot a little further!

However, before I do so - am I missing something painfully obvious; or has someone seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still have this problem, but you need to call

```
new YT.Player(...)
```

instead of calling

```
YT.Player(...)
```

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I missed that off. I did some debugging of the minified code (as far as you can with one character identifiers..) and thinking of it, that would make *a lot* of sense. Doh! I will do a quick test case and then accept your answer, thanks a bunch! :)